# why my c program show me something not logic

Tags: c

I had a problem in my code for tic-tac-toe game
I think everything is ok but when i choose the column and the ligne it shows something wrong
example(morpion[0][2]=1 shows me [0][2]=1 and [1][0]=1 too)
Please someone run the code and check it for me

code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void initialiser(int tableau[2][2])
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
       for(j=0;j<3;j++)
          tableau[i][j]=0;
    }
}
void aficherTableau(int tableau[2][2])
{
    int i,j;
    printf("------------\n");
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            if(tableau[i][j]==0)
            printf(" . |");
            else 
               if(tableau[i][j]==1)
                   printf(" X |");
            else printf(" O |");
        }
    printf("\n------------\n");
    }
}
void saisieJeu(int* x,int* y)
{

    do{
    printf("saisir la ligne et la colonne entre 1 et 3:");
    scanf("%d",x);
    scanf("%d",y);
    }while(*x>2 || *x<0 || *y>2 || *y<0);
      }
int est_occupe_plateau(int tableau[2][2])
{
   int test=1,i,j;
   for(i=0;i<3;i++){
      for(j=0;j<3;j++)
      {
        if(tableau[i][j]==0)
        test=0;
      }
   }
return test;
}
int alignement(int tableau[2][2],int *num_joueur)
{
int boolean,i;
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    if((tableau[i][0]==tableau[i][1] && tableau[i][0]!=0)&& (tableau[i][1]==tableau[i][2]))
    {
        boolean=1;
        if(tableau[i][0]==1)
           *num_joueur=1;
        else *num_joueur=2;  
    }
    else if((tableau[0][i]==tableau[1][i] && tableau[0][i]!=0) && tableau[1][i]==tableau[2][i])
    {
        boolean=1;
        if(tableau[0][i]==1)
           *num_joueur=1;
        else *num_joueur=2  ;
    } 
    else if(((tableau[0][0]==tableau[1][1] && tableau[0][0]!=0) && tableau[1][1]==tableau[2][2]) || 
((tableau[0][2]==tableau[1][1] && tableau[0][2]!=0) && tableau[1][1]==tableau[2][0]))
{
        boolean=1;
        if(tableau[0][0]==1 || tableau[0][2]==1)
           *num_joueur=1;
        else *num_joueur=2; 
}
else {
    boolean =0;
    *num_joueur=0;
     }   
}
return boolean ; 
}
void afficher(int t[2][2])
{
   int i,j;
   for(i=0;i<3;i++)
   {
       for(j=0;j<3;j++)
       printf("%d |",t[i][j]);
       printf("\n");   
   }
}
int main(){
   int plateau[2][2];   
   int x=0,y=0,num_joueur=1,joueur_vainqueur=0,boolean;;
   initialiser(plateau);
   aficherTableau(plateau);
   while(est_occupe_plateau(plateau)==0 && alignement(plateau,&joueur_vainqueur)==0)
   {
       saisieJeu(&x,&y);
       if(num_joueur==1)
       {
           plateau[x][y]=1;
           num_joueur=2;
           aficherTableau(plateau);
       }

       else {
           plateau[x][y]=2;
           num_joueur=1; 
           aficherTableau(plateau);
       }
    }
    boolean=alignement(plateau,&joueur_vainqueur);
    if(joueur_vainqueur==1)
    printf("le joueur 1 est vainqueur");
   else 
      if(joueur_vainqueur==2)
   printf("le joueur 2 est vainqueur");  
   else printf("nulle.");   
   return 0;
  }
```

I had a problem in my code for tic-tac-toe game
I think everything is ok but when i choose the column and the ligne it shows something wrong
example(morpion[0][2]=1 shows me [0][2]=1 and [1][0]=1 too)
Please someone run the code and check it for me
Thanks for paying attention

Comment: `int[2][2]` only has 4 ints. Should be `int[3][3]`. You provide the size, not the index of the last element

Comment: ooooh yeah i forget that XD

Answer (score 1):

You define a tableau of size 2x2, i.e. `int tableau[2][2]`, yet you address the elements as if it were of size 3x3.

Note that array indizes in C start with `0`, such that for an array of size two only `[0]` and `[1]` are valid indizes, but `[2]` is already out of bounds. So you may assign `tableau[0][0]=1` or `tableau[1][1]=1`, but not `tableau[2][2]=1`.

Define your tableaus as `int tableau[3][3]` and let the indizes be from `0` to `2`, then everything should be good.

So why does `morpion[0][2]=1` show `[0][2]=1` and `[1][0]=1`, too`?

Two dimensional arrays are laid out in memory one row after the other, such that `int tableau2D[2][2]` yields the same memory layout as `tableau1D[4]`; `tableau2D[r][c]=1` would be equivalent to `tableau1D[r*2+c]=1`. Hence, `tableau2D[0][2]=1` is memory wise equivalent to `tableau1D[0*2+2]`, i.e. `tableau1D[2]`. And `tableau2D[1][0]` is equivalent to `tableau1D[1*2+0]`, i.e. `tableau1D[2]`. You see, both `tableau2D[0][2]` and `tableau2D[1][0]` will be mapped to the same memory address.